# Best Discovery Protocol implementation

Tags: nodes, peers, node-discovery, devp2p, discovery-protocol

Do you guys know an easy *Discovery Protocol* implementation that is not deprecated and is powerful enough. I've checked some, but all of them are not suitable for my task (reasons below).

Checked implementations:

- [ethereumjs-devp2p](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-devp2p) - Awesome **nodeJS** implementation of **devp2p**, but unfortunately - no API for *Discovery Protocol*
- [pydevp2p](https://pypi.org/project/devp2p/) - **Python** module. Deprecated (At least hasn't updated for a long time). Does not have documentation.

Comment: Why not look at the devP2P implementations in current clients? i.e Geth &  Parity?

Comment: And the first link seems to have some APIs for disco https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-devp2p#distributed-peer-table-dpt--node-discovery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use implementations of existing clients:

- Besu - [Java implementation](https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/tree/master/ethereum/p2p/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/besu/ethereum/p2p)
- Geth - [Go implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/p2p)
- Parity<sup>1</sup> - [Rust implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/tree/master/util/network-devp2p)

<sup>1</sup> At this point, I would be careful to use Parity's implementation because Parity has officially stated it won't maintain the codebase any longer and [judging by the commit activity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/graphs/commit-activity), its starting to show already.